# Angular Web RTC request has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, socket.io, webrtc

I am new to Web RTC and following this tutorial for implementation in Angular.

[Video chats with Angular and WebRTC](https://padymies.medium.com/video-chats-with-angular-and-webrtc-3f892dd0acd6)

I have cloned the repository and when I run the application it gives me following errors.

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O9oOW2l'
> from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy:
> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
> resource.
>
> zone-evergreen.js:2845  GET
> http://localhost:5000/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=O9oOWnh
> net::ERR_FAILED 403

I have changed the cors options in code from

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = {
  url: 'http://localhost:5000', options: {}
};
```

to

```
const config: SocketIoConfig = {
  url: 'http://localhost:5000', options: {
    cors: {
      origin: 'http://localhost:4200/',
      credentials: true,
    }
  }
};
```

as per socket.io documentation but still the errors are shown in browser. How can I solve this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The cors configuration should be done server and client side. Here you have only client side.

Comment: How can I implement both? Can you guide me please

Comment: You can check the offical documentattion [link](https://socket.io/docs/v4/handling-cors/)

Comment: Fix origin: 'http://localhost:4200' without the last /

Comment: I have removed the / but still same error is coming in console.

Comment: I have followed official documentation. I don't know what I am missing.

Answer (score 0):

The configuration I used in server side btw it's express app

```html
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");
const cors = require("cors");

const app = express();
app.use(cors());
const server = http.createServer(app);

const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const io = new Server(server, {
  cors: {
    origin: "*",
  },
});
```